# How do I turn a numpy ndarray into a PyTorch dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a numpy ndarray with a shape (16699, 128, 128), where each element is an image of 128 by 128 pixels, each image normalized to a range of 0 to 1.
Now, to put the image into a neural network model, I have to take each element of the array, convert it to a tensor, and add one extra-dimension with `.unsqueeze(0)` to it to bring it to the format (C, W, H).
So I'd like to simplify all this with the dataloader and dataset methods that PyTorch has to use batches and etc. How I can do it?

This is the method I have now:

```
epochs = 3

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i in range(X):
        y = torch.from_numpy(y[i])
        x = torch.from_numpy(X[i]).unsqueeze(0)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to convert `X` and `y` to two tensors (both with the same length), then wrap them in a [`torch.utils.data.TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=tensordataset#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset).

```py
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

batch_size = 128
dataset = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X).unsqueeze(1), torch.from_numpy(y))
loader = DataLoader(dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)

...

# training loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for x, y in loader:
        # x is a tensor batch of images with shape (batch_size, 1, H, W)
        # y is a tensor with the corresponding labels
        ...
```

Comment: What if the `x` are transformed during training? Will these changes be seen in the original `np.array`?

Comment: @adosar A `DataLoader` returns copies of the dataset tensors, so any changes to `x` in the for loop will not be reflected in the original numpy array.